# need to add upload button in image using html 5

Tags: css, ajax, html

[image: Upload Button]: 
give me the suggestion to add upload button in image using html5 and css and 1.7
    for below java 1.6 image i need to add upload button in the corner of that (+) image..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stylejava.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to Java</h1>
        <div class="imagewrap">
            <button type="submit" class="button" value="Button">
                <img src="../images/symbol1.png" alt="Submit"
                    style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
            </button>
            <img src="../images/java166.jpg" alt="Mountain View"
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
        </div>
        <div class="imagewrap">
            <button type="submit" class="button1" value="Button 1">
                <img src="../images/symbol.png" alt="Submit"
                    style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
            </button>
            <img src="../images/java177.jpg" alt="Mountain Viewm"
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

this is my html5 code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` tag to implement what you want.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tvtespeq/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="img-upload">
<label id="img-label" for="img-upload"></label>
```

**CSS:**

```
#img-label {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    display: block;    
    background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");

    cursor: pointer;    
}

#img-upload {
    display: none;
}
```